# how do you reference element in CSS

Tags: css

I have the following:

```
<tr class="month-header" style="background-image:url(http://i66.tinypic.com/dy85ev.jpg);background-position:center center;background-repeat:no-repeat;background-size:cover;height:300px;text-align:right;">
        <th colspan="14">
            <h1 style="color:#FFF;font-size:200%;font-weight:700;letter-spacing:3px;padding-right:50px;padding-bottom:150px;text-shadow:-1px 0 black, 0 1px black, 1px 0 black, 0 -1px #000;vertical-align:top;">August 2017</h1>
            <a class="copyright-notice" href="http://jaded-night-stock.deviantart.com/art/Dog-Stock-329-391442471" style="color:#FFF;font-size:50%;padding-right:50px;text-align:right;text-decoration:none;vertical-align:bottom;">Photo © Jaded-Night-Stock</a>
        </th>
    </tr>
```

How do I reference all h1 tags that are inside tr tags with a class of "month-header"

I tried .month-header h1 but that didn't work

Comment: yes should work but you are using `style` on `h1` so these properties can only be overwritten by using `!important`: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Specificity

Comment: `.month-header h1` will work, but stylesheets won't override rules defined in that `style` attribute…

Comment: Your approach should work, but if you want to make it a little more specific you could use `tr.month-header h1`, but like Sebastion said you have to use `!important` to overwrite in-line CSS.

Answer (score 0):

Try using the CSS element > Selector, it's specifically suited for
accessing nested tags within parents tags.

In your case:

```
tr > .month-header h1
{
    //your code here
}
```

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

Just add the *table* tags and everything will be fine.
Also, my advice to you - **don't use inline style**.

Good luck :)

```css
.month-header {
    background: url(http://i66.tinypic.com/dy85ev.jpg) no-repeat center center;
    background-size: cover;
    height: 300px;
    text-align: right;
}

.copyright-notice {
    color: #FFF;
    font-size: 50%;
    padding-right: 50px;
    text-align: right;
    text-decoration: none;
    vertical-align: bottom;
}

.month-header h1 {
    color: #FFF;
    font-size: 200%;
    font-weight: 700;
    letter-spacing: 3px;
    padding-right: 50px;
    padding-bottom: 150px;
    text-shadow: -1px 0 black, 0 1px black, 1px 0 black, 0 -1px #000;
    vertical-align: top;
}
```

```html
<table><!-- add open table tag -->
    <tr class="month-header">
        <th colspan="14">
            <h1 class="outline-text">August 2017</h1>
            <a class="copyright-notice" href="http://jaded-night-stock.deviantart.com/art/Dog-Stock-329-391442471">
                Photo © Jaded-Night-Stock
            </a>
        </th>
    </tr>
</table><!-- add close table tag -->
```

Answer (score 0):

You can reference all h1 tags that are inside tr tags with a class of "month-header" by using important after every statement:

```
.month-header h1 {
  color: red!important;
  font-size: 300%!important;
}
```

PS. This one is nice to hang on your wall: [Specifishity](https://specifishity.com/specifishity.pdf).

PPS. This one is cool too: http://cssspecificity.com/